# react native securetextEntry issue on ios build working in simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

i have create a sign in form where i'm taking username and password as input. the issue in on simulator i m able to insert password and its visible as encrypt(black dots) but when i create a build password input is showing blank input and keyboard is not opening.

Versions:
"react": "16.13.1"
"react-native": "~0.63.4"

custom input component

```
const BorderedTextInputWithIcon = React.forwardRef((props, ref = null) => (
  <View style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    {props.icon && (
      <Icon
        name={props.icon}
        size={20}
        color={Colors.CYAN}
        style={{ position: "absolute", left: 10, top: 30, zIndex: 1 }}
      />
    )}
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      style={{ ...styles.textInput, ...props.style }}
      ref={ref}
      placeholderTextColor={Colors.LIGHT_GRAY}
    />
    {props.rightIcon && (
      <Icon
        name={props.rightIcon}
        size={18}
        color={Colors.WHITE}
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          right: 30,
          top: 35,
          zIndex: 1,
          color: Colors.CYAN,
          borderRadius: 20,
          padding: 3,
        }}
      />
    )}
  </View>
));
```

```
 <BorderedTextInputWithIcon
                ref={(ref) => (this.password = ref)}
                keyboardType="default"
                placeholder="Password"
                style={styles.input}
                icon="eye"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                value={password}
                onChangeText={(value) => this.handleOnChange("password", value)}
                onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmit}
              />
```

calling as this in sign in screen

Comment: Try with hardcode the secureTextEntry props in TextInput and debug. https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#securetextentry

Comment: its working with iphone xs but this issue is with iphone after that. i tried hardcoring also.

Comment: Can upgrade React to latest version. As well as react native 0.64.2